# Adding multiple columns to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have a data frame `df` such as:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=101:105)
```

Now adding a single column to a specific row works:

```
df[4,"d"] <- 5
df
#   a   b  d
# 1 1 101 NA
# 2 2 102 NA
# 3 3 103 NA
# 4 4 104  5
# 5 5 105 NA
```

But adding multiple columns simultaneously doesn't!

```
df[3,c("b","f","g")] <- c(6,7,8)
#Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

What gives?

The long way to achieve this, of course, is:

```
df[3,"b"] <- 6
df[3,"f"] <- 7
df[3,"g"] <- 8
```

But is this really the easiest (and the right) way?

Comment: Have you tried `cbind()` to lump the columns together?

Comment: @ilir To `cbind()`, I'd have to create the entire column vector. The desirable way is to specify certain row(s), and have the rest automatically filled with NAs. Unless I'm completely misinterpreting what you meant.

Comment: No you understood correctly. I did not notice the row index. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can first assign new columns to the data, and then fill them by row (or by column).

```
df[ ,c("e","f","g")] <- NA
df
#   a   b  e  f  g
# 1 1 101 NA NA NA
# 2 2 102 NA NA NA
# 3 3 103 NA NA NA
# 4 4 104 NA NA NA
# 5 5 105 NA NA NA
df[3 ,c("e","f","g")] <- 6:8
df
#   a   b  e  f  g
# 1 1 101 NA NA NA
# 2 2 102 NA NA NA
# 3 3 103  6  7  8
# 4 4 104 NA NA NA
# 5 5 105 NA NA NA
```

Comment: And if it's unknown whether the columns to be assigned values already exist in the dataset or not?

Comment: Well you didn't mention that in the original question. You can find out if they already exist with calling `names(df)` before you do anything to the data.

Comment: I was about to post an answer to the effect of `df[c("e","f","g")] <- NA; df[3,c("e","f","g")] <- c(6,7,8)`, which differs from this answer in filling the unassigned values with NA instead of zero.

Comment: True. It can all be done with a series of checks and multiple statements, but I wonder if an elegant way to do this exists.
Anyway, adding the detail to the question for clarity.

Comment: That's probably better actually, since those values are probably not zero.  Good call, I just woke up :)  I'll edit

Comment: @user2175594, `names(df)[names(df) %in% c("e", "f", "g")]` will tell you which of e, f, or g already exist in the data set.

Answer (score 1):

A more automated way to achieve this is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=101:105)
cols <- c("e", "f", "g")
vals <- c(6, 7, 8)
sapply(1:length(cols), function(i)
   df[3, cols[i]] <<- vals[i]
)
df
```

Which gives:

```
  a   b  e  f  g
1 1 101 NA NA NA
2 2 102 NA NA NA
3 3 103  6  7  8
4 4 104 NA NA NA
5 5 105 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Yep. That's what I finally ended up doing. But I'm not sure I get the logic of the values not filling up automatically in the case of multiple columns together.

Comment: I think it's a sensible behavior of the `<-` operator: you set only the value of the 3rd element in a vector (column), the rest remain *unknown* == *missing* == *not available*...